# Problem with Facebook PHP SDK wall post when changing the Canvas URL

Tags: php, facebook, canvas, facebook-graph-api

I made an iFrame FB application for a company, which is perfectly working when stored in my server but when I moved it to the company server, and change the Canvas URL, the application worked fine apart from the $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment); function which doesn't work anymore.

I wrote a simple test script doing the next actions:
1) creating a session
2) sending a post to the wall

In both cases (my server and the company server), the session is always correctly created but the post to the wall is not working for the company.

I, of course, already tried to clear the cache, uninstall the application after changing the Canvas URL, but no luck. Still the session is created but the post to the wall never works.

I also tried to move the application from my server to another folder in my server (different Canvas URL but same domain) and it worked fine. So maybe this means that the problem lies into the domain change in the Canvas URL ???

Note : Both my server and the company server use PHP 5.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: do you have rights to post on the wall? (publish_stream)

Comment: Yes, i do. Otherwise I could not even post from my server.

Comment: do you pass the access token in $attachment variable?

Comment: So far no, but yesterday, I've been doing some tests passing the access token, and printing the access token on screen. Same problem: on my server OK, on the company server, access token is printing fine, but no post to the wall!

Comment: $this->_facebook->api("/me/feed",'post',array('access_token'=>urlencode($this->_fb_session['access_token']),'message'=>'testing graph api: feed posts!!!'));

this is how I pass the access_token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : the fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt file was missing. The strange thing is that it was also missing on my server and it was working without it.

Anyway, problem solved!